# Почему props выводятся в консоль, но при рендеринге возникает ошибка TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux

Всем привет, делаю проект, сейчас перевожу на Redux получение данных. Я пока что не очень в хорошо в нем разбираюсь. Проблема в том, что я получаю данные из редакса в пропсы родительского компонента, а из него опрокидываю их в дочерний. Когда я просто вывожу данные в консоль, они выводятся нормально, но как только я пытаюсь их отрендерить, получаю undefined и в консоли(хотя до этого выводились нормально), и ошибку в методе render(). Изначально получала данные из файла chatsData.
Не подскажете, с чем это может быть связано?
Буду благодарна за любую помощь и объяснение!

Вот код этого компонента и контейнера родительского компонента, через который получаются данные

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Messenger} from '../components/Messenger';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import {chatLoadActions, chatMessageSendActions} from '../actions/chats';

class MessengerContainerClass extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onHandleMessageSend = this.onHandleMessageSend.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.chatLoadActions();
    }

    onHandleMessageSend(newMessage, newAuthor){
        const {chatId} = this.props;
        this.props.chatMessageSendActions({text: newMessage, author: newAuthor, id: nanoid(), chatId});

    }



    render(){
        const {messages, title, allChats} = this.props;
        return (
            <Messenger messages={messages}
                        title={title}
                        chats={allChats}
                        onHandleMessageSend={this.onHandleMessageSend}
              />
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        chatLoadActions: () => dispatch(chatLoadActions()),
        chatMessageSendActions: (message) => dispatch(chatMessageSendActions(message))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) =>{
    const chats = state.chats.entries; 
    const {match} = ownProps;
    let messages = null;
    let chatsTitle = null;

    if(match && chats[+match.params.id]){
        messages = chats[+match.params.id].messages;
        chatsTitle = chats[+match.params.id].title;
    }

    return {
        messages,
        chatId: match ? match.params.id : null,
        title: chatsTitle,
        allChats: chats,
    };
}

export const MessengerContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessengerContainerClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import ChatBubbleRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChatBubbleRounded';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {chats} from '../../helpers/chatsData';

const styles = {
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginLeft: '20px',
    borderRight: '1px solid gray',
  },
};

class ChatListClass extends Component{
  render(){
    const {classes, chats} = this.props;
    console.log('chatList:', chats);
    return (
      <List className={classes.root}>
        <h3>Your chats</h3>
        <hr />
        {chats.map((chat) => (
          <ListItem key={chat.id}>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Avatar>
                <ChatBubbleRoundedIcon />
              </Avatar>
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <Link to={`/chats/${chat.id}`}>
               <ListItemText primary={chat.title}
                    secondary={`Tap to see your ${chat.title} messages`}/>
            </Link>
         </ListItem>
       ))}

    </List>
  );
}
}

export const ChatList = withStyles(styles)(ChatListClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я разобралась, все заработало, как только я использовала Array.from() в родительском компоненте;

```
    render(){
    const {messages, onHandleMessageSend, addNewChat, title, chats} = this.props;
    const chatsArr = Array.from(chats);
    return(<>
     <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Header />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
            <ChatsForm onSend={addNewChat}/>
            <ChatList chats={chatsArr}/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
                {messages ?<MessagesList  items={messages} title={title}/>:<div className="not-choosen">Choose chat</div>}
                {messages && <MessageForm onSend={onHandleMessageSend} />}
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
        </>
    );   
}
```